# Работа со строками

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Помогите решить проблему. Есть строка - `String str = "sometextsometextsometext";`.

Я хочу парсить её на составляющие, например, substring'ом. Т.е. пишу while, и в нем: `string par = str.substring(0,3); str.substring(4);` (удаляю до 4 символа или вместе с 4-м) и т.д. Но как в этом случае мне поймать конец строки? Что написать в условие while?

Comment: У вас есть длина строки, используйте ее, чтобы выработать условие выхода из цикла.

Comment: @a_gura, так а как тут длиной строки воспользоваться? Не понимаю. Я же не по одному символу удаляю, а по 4.

Comment: @compl И что, вычесть 4 из длины строки никак?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Смотри](http://ideone.com/i3CMQA)

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static int CONST = 4;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

         String str = "sometextsometextsometext";
         while(str.length() !=0 && (str.length()>CONST)){
             String par = str.substring(0,3);
             str = str.substring(CONST);

             System.out.println(str);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: @zamutil Что если строка на определенной итерации цикла будет ненулевой длины, но меньше 3-х? ;)

Comment: @a_gura
какой вопрос, такой и ответ:)
я не спорю, что это не круто, но может поможет ТСу немного подумать